# Ajuda com algoritmo String

Tags: java, string, substring

Preciso fazer um programa no qual o usuário digita uma cadeia de caracteres e uma subcadeia, e informar quantas vezes essa subcadeia ocorre na cadeia principal. 
Ex:
Cadeia principal:"banana"
Subcadeia: "na"
Repetições: 2.

Ja pensei em usar um vetor de String, ou ainda o comando Substring mas não consegui nada até agora.

A unica tentativa que eu consegui ao menos montar o codigo foi:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    int controle, contador;
    contador = 0;
    String cadeia, palavra, substring;
    substring="";

    System.out.println("Insira uma frase e/ou palavras: ");
    cadeia = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Selecione uma palavra a ser verificada na cadeia: ");
    palavra = s.nextLine();
    char inicioSubstring = palavra.charAt(0);
    int fnalSubstring = (palavra.length()-1);
    char finalSubstring = palavra.charAt(fnalSubstring);
    int inicioSubs = -1;
    int fimSubs = -1;


    for (controle = 0; controle < cadeia.length(); controle++)
    {
        if (cadeia.charAt(controle) == inicioSubstring)
        {
            inicioSubs = controle;
        }
        if (cadeia.charAt(controle) == finalSubstring)
        {
            fimSubs = controle;
        }
        if(inicioSubs != -1 && fimSubs !=  -1)
        {
            substring = cadeia.substring(inicioSubs, fimSubs);
            if(substring.equalsIgnoreCase(palavra))
            {
                contador++;
            }   
        }   
    }
    System.out.println(contador);
```

Comment: E o que já tentou fazer? Demonstre que teve algum esforço tentando algo e adicione na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para a parte de contabilizar o total de vezes de determinada String no termo você pode utilizar [expressão regular](https://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-basicos-sobre-expressoes-regulares-em-java/27539). Por exemplo:

```
String termo = "banana";
Pattern padrao = Pattern.compile("na");
Matcher combinacao = padrao.matcher(termo);

int contador = 0;
while (combinacao.find()) {
    contador += 1;
}

System.out.println(contador);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mesmo sem expressões regulares consegue fazer o que pretende com relativa facilidade utilizando o método [`indexOf` da `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) e o [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) que permite indicar apenas a partir de uma determinada posição.

Para ficar mais claro deixo aqui apenas a declaração dos 2 métodos em causa:

> `public int indexOf(String str)`
>
> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.

E

> `public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`
>
> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index.

Implementação:

```
System.out.println("Insira uma frase e/ou palavras: ");
String cadeia = s.nextLine();

System.out.println("Selecione uma palavra a ser verificada na cadeia: ");
String palavra = s.nextLine();

int contador = 0;
int posicao = cadeia.indexOf(palavra);
while (posicao != -1){ //enquanto encontra a palavra
    contador++;
    posicao = cadeia.indexOf(palavra, posicao + palavra.length());
}

System.out.println(contador);
```

Saida:

```
Insira uma frase e/ou palavras: 
banana
Selecione uma palavra a ser verificada na cadeia: 
na
2
```

[Veja este código no Ideone](https://ideone.com/VUjjrL)